# How do I apply conditional logic to determine which master page to display in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 master pages and a single content page. How do I show employees one master page and customers a different one?

This is for an asp.net mvc app.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the master in the View method in your action:

```
return View("MyPage", isCustomer ? "CustomerMasterPage" : "EmployeeMasterPage")
```